# What is better? #define getmax(a, b) or int getmax(a, b)

Tags: c, runtime, c-preprocessor

If I need a simple function for my program, lets say to determine max of two numbers,  is it better to define it like:

```
#define getmax(a, b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

or

```
int getmax(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}
```

I made a simple program that prints `getmax(a, b)`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define getmax(a, b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for( j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            printf("%d\n", getmax(i, j));
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include<stdio.h>

int getmax(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for( i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for( j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            printf("%d\n", getmax(i, j));
    return 0;
}
```

I tested both programs 10 times and calculated the average runtime. For the first program average is 0.8880s and for the second program average is 0.8575. What is better to use and is there any other difference than runtime?

Comment: this is not a duplicate of that question. this is asking about c functions, not inlined c++ functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int getmax(int a, int b)
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}
```

is better than

```
#define getmax(a, b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

Because consider doing

```
getmax(a++,b++);
```

With define macro you get

```
((a++)>(b++)?(a++):(b++));
```

And this is propably not what you want.